# Converting 1d vector into 2d vector

Tags: vector, 2d, type-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > DV;   //2d vector
  std::vector<double>temp(8,0.0);  //1d vector

  temp[0] = 1;
  temp[1] = 2;
  temp[2] = 3;
  temp[3] = 4;
  temp[4] = 5;
  temp[5] = 6;
  temp[6] = 7;
  temp[7] = 8;

  DV.resize(3, temp); 

  for (int i = 0; i < DV.size(); i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < DV.size(); j++)
      {
        std::cout << DV[i][j];
      }
  }
std::cin.get();
}
```

The convertion actually works but it does not give the expected the result. The output should be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8
```

and it outputs:

```
123123123
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a method to automagically turn a 1D vector into a 2D one.  It's not too hard to do manually, though...

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> DoubleVector2D;

DoubleVector2D boxed(size_t cols, std::vector<double> values) {
    DoubleVector2D result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        if (i % cols == 0) result.resize(result.size() + 1);
        result[i / cols].push_back(values[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

With that done, you can call `boxed(3, temp)` to get back a vector of vectors of doubles.  At that point, you just have to loop over them.

```
for (auto row : DV) {
    for (auto value : row) {
         std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you're stuck without decent C++11 support, you may need to use counters or iterators.

```
for (int row = 0; row < DV.size(); ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < DV[i].size(); ++col) {
        std::cout << DV[row][col] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < DV.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < DV.size(); j++){
        std::cout << DV[i][j] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Your issue is how you are printing your values to the standard output.

Comment: If you look closely, the output is still different. It doesn't print from 1 to 8.

Comment: Still seems it'd only print the first `DV.size()` columns.  The OP's current code looks like it wants to print out `12345678\n12345678\n12345678`.  If it doesn't, then its vectors are being used wrong.

Comment: i guess vectors are being used wrongly, idk how to fix it tho